# Azure service bus premium namespace cost

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

Does azure service bus namespace requires dedicated messaging unit? Or is it possible to create multiple premium namespaces using same messaging unit? In other words is there extra cost associated with creating premium namespace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Premium tier requires to choose number of messaging units. The number is between one and eight. The MUs are applied to a single namespace. With Premium tier it's always one namespace. If you have two namespaces, each will have its own MUs that are not shared.